# Get list of widgets for QGuiApplication

Tags: c++, qt, qapplication

I need to get list of UI elements on the application main window (all windows, doesn't matter).
The problem is that there is no `topLevelWidgets()` function in `QGuiApplication`, it is in `QApplication`. Of course I could use `QApplication` instead of `QGuiApplication`, but the application already exists and I can't change source codes. I'm writing plugin.

I think if `Qt` allows you to write place UI elements for application using `QGuiApplication` class, it should give some way to get those elements, but maybe I'm wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is with QWindowList QGuiApplication::topLevelWindows()? If you get a list of the top windows?

Comment: I can get topLevelWindows, but it doesn't give me list of UI elements (buttons, text boxes and so on...), it gives me pointer to my window and that's it.

Comment: This Example is not working... The docs explain this: QApplication specializes QGuiApplication with some functionality needed for QWidget-based applications. It handles widget specific initialization, finalization, and provides session management.

Comment: Yes. It appears that you cannot create widgets without creating QApplication. The application I had was using QGuiApplication, but it was using `QQuickView` and `QML`, which is OpenGL actually, not widgets as `QDeclarativeView`. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 QList<QWidget *> widgets = centralWidget::findChildren<QWidget *>();
```

This will get all of the widgets of the MainWindow.

Comment: As far as I understood centralWidget is a property of `QMainWindow` class. I don't have a pointer to `QMainWindow`. All I have is the pointer to `QGuiApplication` and I need to get all UI elements on the window or widget or whatever is used.

Comment: change the centralwidget to the name of your qguiapplication.

Comment: Actually it appears that I can't create widgets for QGuiApplication. That's strange, it doesn't work for my example. I need to check the source codes for the application once again.

Comment: Anyway, this answers my question regarding getting widgets from QGuiApplication. Thanks.